# How can I find download link of linux softwares?

Tags: software-recommendation, software-installation, software-center, package-management

I want download link of sofwares to download them with a download manager.

Could you please help to find download link of any Linux software?

Comment: I'm guessing you have more machines and don't want to download the same software twice or more times? Please when you ask a question be clear and add all the possible details.

Comment: @xangua Thanks for your attention, Yes I don't want to download the same software twice and I don't want to download with terminal, I want download link of softwares to download with a download manager. How can I find download link of softwares? Otherwise is it possible to find download link for any software easily?

Answer (score 0):

Please try aria2 it's command-line base but best tool for downloads.

$ sudo apt-get install aria2

usage (without quotes) :

$ aria2c "http file link"

Comment: My problem is that: How can find download link of softwares?